# Manually setting parameters' data in PyTorch model

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I train ResNet34 model on CIFAR-10 dataset. I'm simulating federated learning: I have one server model and multiple local models; all training happens on learning models and sometimes I synchronize them with the server model. Since I store models as lists of trainable parameters, synchronization is the following:

```
def communicate_to_server(*, local_data, prev_local_data, server_data, n_machines):
  for i in range(len(local_data)):
    server_data[i] += (local_data[i] - prev_local_data[i]) / n_machines 
    local_data[i][:] = server_data[i]
    prev_local_data[i][:] = server_data[i]
```

So, the server model collects updates and shares its model with a local model.

To perform training for the local model, I have an instance of ResNet34 network. When I want to make an SGD step, I set model parameters to local model:

```
def set_params(model, data):
  params = [param for param in model.parameters() if param.requires_grad]
  for param, d in zip(params, data):
    param.data = d
```

And then do usual loss-backpropagation function stuff (I'm using `optim.SGD` with `0` momentum).

**My question:** Am I allowed to do these operations? I.e. am I allowed to simply substitute `param.data` with new values? Am I allowed to do assignments like `local_data[i][:] = server_data[i]` (I tried to insert `.detach()` in all possible places, it didn't seem to affect anything)? Can I be sure that I don't create any weird computational graph connections or don't break existing ones?

While I don't have direct evidence that something is wrong, I'm concerned that my testing accuracy is much lower compared to what the usual SGD achieves (77% vs 90%), while training accuracy is higher (100% vs 99%).